# How to use unicode in Jekyll code highlight?

Tags: unicode, escaping, jekyll

I'm new to Jekyll. Just trying to use Unicode (Greek letters) in a Jekyll highlight block. Is there a way to escape the highlight block and use plain HTML?

The following code is working.

{% highlight Racket %}
(define foo
   (lambda (x) x))
{% endhighlight %}

And I would like to replace that "lambda" with a "λ".

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your using utf-8 (jekyll default), you can use any [utf-8 character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) as is.

So : `{% highlight Racket %} (define foo (λ(x) x)) {% endhighlight %}` is ok.

Comment: So, you can certainly approve this answer.